# Instantiating a class with injected constructor in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I was wondering if it's possible to make an object of a class that has a constructor with an injection of another class.

The class i want to instantiate:

```
using ClearBlog.IRepository;
using ClearBlog.Models;

namespace ClearBlog.Areas.Admin.Classes
{
    public class AdminArticleTags
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<ArticleTag> _db = null;

        public AdminArticleTags(IGenericRepository<ArticleTag> db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public int InsertNew(int article, int tag)
        {
            // do smt here
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the `InsertNew` method of the above class in another class like this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ClearBlog.Models;
using ClearBlog.Helpers;
using ClearBlog.IRepository;
using ClearBlog.Areas.Admin.Classes;

namespace ClearBlog.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class Someclass : Controller
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<Tag> _db = null;

        public Someclass(IGenericRepository<Tag> db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AdminArticleTags at = new AdminArticleTags();
            at.InsertNew(10, 15);
        }
     }
 }
```

That is not possible now because of the constructor expecting an `IGenericRepository`.

Is it even possible?

If it's not, then what way do you recommend? mind the fact that I need to use the `IGenericRepository` that is the interface used by Ninject to bind to an implementation.

**edit:**

what I'm trying to do is very simple. I just want to make an object of `AdminArticleTags` and access it's method inside `Someclass`. even if i make an parameterless constructor for `AdminArticlesTags` it gives errors because it not going to inject `IGenericRepository` for that object. (because of constructor)

***How would i make an object of `AdminArticlesTags` and use its methods??***

**edit2:**

this is where i do Ninject bindings:

```
using Ninject;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ClearBlog.IRepository;
using ClearBlog.Repository;
using AutoMapper;

namespace ClearBlog.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
        {
            kernel = kernelParam;
            AddBindings();
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }
        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }
        private void AddBindings()
        {
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
            kernel.Rebind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(context => Mapper.Engine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example isn't making too much sense. You're instansiating the same class you're running inside, which also inherits controller?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'll fix it now. it's a typo.

Comment: Are you looking to inject the existing instance of `IGenericRepository`? Use `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IGenericRepository>();` and pass that into the constructor.

Comment: @James `Someclass` has it's own version of `IGenericRepository` with a different type. it's not going to work for `AdminArticlesTags`

Comment: @VSG24, do you need a new instance of `AdminArticleTags` each time the `Index` action is invoked?

Comment: @VSG24, you mentioned that you are using NInject. Can you show how? I asking this because there are many ways for that.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Doesn't really matter I guess. but maybe yes.

Comment: @YacoubMassad made an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Constructor Injection.

If you don't care about obtaining a new instance of `AdminArticleTags` every time, then simply inject a `AdminArticleTags` into the controller like this:

```
public class Someclass : Controller
{
    private readonly AdminArticleTags m_AdminArticleTags;

    public Someclass(AdminArticleTags aat)
    {
        m_AdminArticleTags = aat;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       m_AdminArticleTags.InsertNew(15, 42);
    }
}
```

Since you are using Ninject, it would be able to create the controller and pass the correct dependency.

If you require a new instance everytime inside the `Index` action, then you need some kind of factory. You can use the `Func` class like this:

```
public class Someclass : Controller
{
    private readonly Func<AdminArticleTags> m_AdminArticleTagsFactory;

    public Someclass(Func<AdminArticleTags> factory)
    {
        m_AdminArticleTagsFactory = factory;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       AdminArticleTags at = m_AdminArticleTagsFactory();
       at.InsertNew(15, 42);
    }
}
```

In this case, you would have to install the Ninject.Extensions.Factory nuget package. This will allow the support of resolving `Func` based factories. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Func).

An alternative to `Func` based factories are factory interfaces. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface).

Comment: It worked. Your examples were also very useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Yacoub Massad, why would you need a new instance everytime inside Index? What this could help you? Because having the dependency injection as it is makes the work. I dont get why would be useful to instantiate AdminArticleTags everytime with the Func thing? Would like to learn. Thanks a lot

Comment: @VAAA, I think that in well designed applications, you don't needs to instantiate instances every time you need to call a dependency. But many applications are not well-designed and you might work with a code base where existing classes are designed in a way that forces you to instantiate. This is true for example when the instantiated "dependency" contains state that should start from scratch at some point.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes. you can inject code even when the class has a parameterized constructor. though, it depends on how and with what technique/framework you inject.
2. what you are doing in the example is not injection. just a simple instanciation. in addition, your code will not compile because you did not define an empty or a default constructor.

maybe if you give more details about you are trying to achieve it will be easier to assist specifically.